# How to generate dynamic URL from json data?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to use php to add a custom url to http://localhost/test/equity.php for the url displays the data from this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/MSFT/book',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
      document.getElementById("stockprice").innerHTML = data.quote.symbol + " - Brandname";
    }
    });
```

For the url looks like http://localhost/test/quote/{symbol}

Comment: Where does the PHP fit into this? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to perform a redirect?

Comment: When I call the json data.quote.symbol I'd like it passed to a custom url quote/{symbol} here. Perhaps before the page loads or during page load. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Use php to add a custom url to [URL]"

Comment: I'm trying to use this json data to display /symbol